# Solve equation involving modular arithmetic: $92x + 2y^2 \equiv z \mod 9$ with conditions on $x$ and $y$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Solve for $z$ if $92x + 2y^2 \equiv z \mod 9$, when $x \equiv 7 \mod 9$ & $y \equiv 3 \mod 9$

Just having an issue with this question.
I'm unsure how to proceed especially when looking at $2y^2$ and subbing $y \equiv  3 \mod 9$.

How would I solve for $z$?

Answer (score 0):

Taking our formula and making substitutions $$92x +2y^2  \equiv z \pmod 9 \\ 2(7) +2(3)^2  \equiv z \pmod 9 \\ 14 + 18  \equiv z \pmod 9 \\ 7 + 0  \equiv z \pmod 9 \\ 7 \equiv z \pmod 9 \\$$